# Find number of distinct paths by which a string can be derived

Tags: string, algorithm, dynamic-programming

There is a secret message that is a string of length at least 2 containing only the characters A..Z.

Apply a sequence of "operations" to it. An Operation is shown in the example.

Given the final encrypted string, count the number of possible ways you could have produced this string using **one or more** repeated operations applied to a source string.  Operations are distinct even if they give the same encryption of your secret message.  I.E. : There are four distinct separate ways to obtain AAA from AA.

Here is an example:

The encrypted string is: **ABABA**. The output would be: **8**. Here are the different ways you could have produced ABABA:

1. Start with AB -> AB+A -> AB+ABA
2. Start with AB -> AB+A -> ABA+BA
   3.Start with ABA -> AB+ABA
3. Start with ABA -> ABA+BA
4. Start with BA -> A+BA -> AB+ABA
5. Start with BA -> A+BA -> ABA+BA
6. Start with ABAB -> ABAB+A
7. Start with BABA -> A+BABA

Could you please help suggest an algorithm to solve this. I thought of trying recursion but on bigger inputs my code runs way to slow.

Comment: Smells like dynamic programming to me.  Notice at each step the string gets larger, so working backwards recursively will always terminate.

Comment: I thought so to. Yet, I haven't had much practice in dynamic programming and so have no clue how to approach this problem.

Comment: Can you give an example of a "big input" that may run too slow for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice that, at each step of your derivation, you wind up with a substring of the "encrypted" string.  There are quadratically many (i.e. O(n^2)) such substrings.

You can find the number of ways to derive the final string from each of its suffixes and prefixes straightforwardly.

So, you have quadratically many possible subproblems, and you can break a problem down into a complete set of subproblems, do the counting on each subproblem, and add the results up.

You get a dynamic programming algorithm out of this by solving each subproblem only once.  This dynamic programming algorithm can be made to run in cubic time.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't think I fully understand the solution. If possible could you give me pseudocode or just an example to illustrate how it works? Sorry again, I am trying to learn dynamic programming but still struggling.

Comment: @user3188300: Where do you get lost?

Comment: I don't get how you break up the string and then get the number of ways from suffixes and prefixes.

Comment: There are linearly many ways to break up the string; take each prefix and each suffix and see if you can get from there to the desired string in one step.  Then you multiply that number by the number of ways to get that prefix/suffix.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is correct, but here's a recursive attempt in JavaScript:

```
function f(str){
    var total = 0

    function g(ptr,len){
        for (var i=1; i<= (len%2 == 0 ? len/2 - 1: (len - 1)/2); i++){
            var left = str.substr(ptr,len - i),
                suffix = str.substr(ptr + len - i,i),
                right = str.substr(ptr + i,len - i),
                prefix = str.substr(ptr,i),
                recurseL = false,
                recurseR = false

            if (suffix == left.substr(-i)){
                total++
                recurseL = true
            }
            if (suffix == left.substr(0,i)){
                total++
                recurseL = true
            }
            if (prefix == right.substr(-i)){
                total++
                recurseR = true
            }
            if (prefix == right.substr(0,i)){
                total++
                recurseR = true
            }

            if (recurseR)
                g(ptr + i,len - i)
            if (recurseL)
                g(ptr,len - i)
        }
        return total
    }

    return g(0,str.length)
}

f("ABABA")
```

Output:

```
8
```